# Finding a Bash script's Runfiles as generated by Bazel

Tags: bash

When building a `sh_binary` with dependencies using Bazel, a tree of Runfiles containing the dependencies is generated:

```
my_executable
my_executable.sh
my_executable.runfiles/
    __main__/
        a_dependency/
            lib_dependency.sh
```

When deploying such a binary to a typical Unix filesystem, one would install the above file tree to `/usr/local/opt/my_executable` for example. Binaries however are usually linked to the `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/my_executable/my_executable /usr/local/bin/my_executable
```

Like this, it is possible to run the executable as `my_executable` from anywhere on the system. However the trivial approach of finding the runfiles with

```
RUNFILES="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}.runfiles/__main__"
```

then fails since `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` refers to the symlink. Preferably it would be possible to find Runfiles for an arbitrary number of "indirections" using symlinks. The following snippet provides a cross-platform implementation, that searches for a script's Runfiles by successively following symlinks.

```
# Determine the script's executable name
if [[ ! -v EXEC_NAME ]]; then
  export EXEC_NAME="${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}"
fi

# Determine the script's runfiles location, possibly resolving symlinks
if [[ ! -v RUNFILES ]]; then
  EXEC_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
  while [[ ! -a "$EXEC_PATH.runfiles" ]]; do
    if [[ ! -h "$EXEC_PATH" ]]; then
      printf "$EXEC_NAME: error: could not find runfiles\n" 1>&2
      exit 1
    fi
    EXEC_PATH=$(readlink "$EXEC_PATH")
  done
  export EXEC_PATH
  export RUNFILES="$EXEC_PATH.runfiles/__main__"
fi
```

And later in the script, it is then possible to use the dependency like this:

```
source "$RUNFILES/a_dependency/lib_dependency.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following snippet provides a cross-platform implementation

That looks correct, but the script requires Bash 4, and I don't see any validation of that.

Actually, the only Bash 4 feature is the `-v VAR` operator of `[[`,
used as `[[ ! -v VAR ]]`.
I would replace that with `[[ ! "$VAR" ]]`,
even if it's not exactly the same thing,
but probably good enough.

---

Do you really need the `[[ ! -v EXEC_NAME ]]` check?
I don't see a point in a caller overriding this,
so I would drop the condition.

From the snippet it's not clear why this variable is exported with the `export` keyword.
I would review this point, and if there is no reason to export it,
then drop the `export`.

---

It seems to me the script is intended to be *executed*,
as opposed to being *sourced*.
In this case, you could use `$0` as the name of the executable,
no need for the tedious `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`.

---

According to `help test`:

> ```
> -a FILE        True if file exists.
> ...
> -e FILE        True if file exists.
> ```

Although using `-a` is correct, I prefer `-e`, because it's easy to associate with the word "exists".
I had to look up `help test` to verify what is `-a`.

---

Instead of `printf "...\n"` it's simpler to write `echo "..."`,
the `\n` is automatically added,
and the posted snippet doesn't use any interesting feature of `printf`.

---

Instead of:

> ```
> EXEC_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
> ...
> export EXEC_PATH
> ```

I would write:

```
export EXEC_PATH="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

Comment: It's actually quite easy to replicate the functionality of `[[ -v VAR ]]` in a POSIX shell: `[ -n "${VAR+set}" ]`. `printf` vs `echo` is probably a minor issue here, but `printf` still beats plain `echo` in portability and predictability. From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/85612: "All in all, you don't know what `echo "$var"` will output unless you can make sure that `$var` doesn't contain backslash characters and doesn't start with `-`". You can't prevent filenames from containing backslash characters or starting with `-`, so I would rather type that extra `\n` character here.

Comment: Your last suggestion is not equivalent to the OP's code (though I think the OP's code is also error-prone): you're not exporting the `EXEC_PATH=$(readlink "$EXEC_PATH")` in the `while` loop. Otherwise, I agree with your other points.